# 65G SQL Server database has 5.5G of data in tempdb when not in use

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, datafile

I have a SQL Server instance with 1 production database (also ReportServer dbs) that is 65G.  tempdb is 5.5G (well, actually much bigger but 5.5G is in use) when server is not in use.  I believe this is not normal.  How do I diagnose what is causing this space to be filled and not released?

Comment: are you able to run the standard report **Disk Usage by Table**? Right click the tempdb>Reports>Disk Usage by Table.

Answer (score 2):

### Non-temporary user objects

Maybe there are non-temporary user tables in tempdb.  These wouldn't get cleaned up automatically (unless the server is restarted).  You can check for them like this:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [type] = 'U';
```

To release this space, you'll need to manually drop these tables using `DROP TABLE` statements.  Make sure no one is still using them first

### Sleeping sessions keeping temp objects alive

Another possibility is that someone created a temp table, and their session is still active.  I created a temp table using the Stack Overflow sample database and left the session open:

```
SELECT * INTO #Users FROM dbo.Users;
```

Checked space usage:

[image: screenshot of disk usage report in SSMS]

All 4 tempdb files are using about 15 MB of space.

You can see that the session is still open by checking `sp_WhoIsActive` with the option to show sleeping spids:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_WhoIsActive @show_sleeping_spids = 2;
```

[image: screenshot of query results showing the SELECT INTO query with tempdb allocations]

Look for sessions that have tempdb allocations, or otherwise suspicious sessions that have been open for a long time.

If I close the window for session 53 in SSMS, and then re-check `sp_WhoIsActive`, the query is gone.  And now I check tempdb space usage again:

[image: screenshot of disk usage report in SSMS]

You can see that "Space Used" dropped in all 4 files.

To release space that's being held like this, you'll need to either:

- track down the person in the `login_name` field and ask them to end their session, or
- kill the session using [the `KILL` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)